# Activity lags when loading

Tags: android, performance, android-studio, android-activity

I have an activity that lags (quite severely) when it's started. The lag usually lasts for under a second, but it's noticeable and I don't want it to be.

I'm not sure what's causing it to lag, but I need to fix it so that it's smooth as butter when it's loading.

Here is the activity:

```
public class ProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout;

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;

    private LinearLayoutManager layoutManager;

    private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;

    private EndlessRecyclerViewScrollListener scrollListener;

    private int userId;

    private User user;

    private List<Object> data = new ArrayList<>();

    protected UserAdapter userAdapter;

    private TextView username, userNumPosts;
    private ImageView userBackground, userColor, userIcon;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);

        // Get userId from intent
        userId = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("userId");

        // Check if the user is in realm db
        user = getRealm().where(User.class)
                .equalTo("id", userId)
                .findFirst();

        // Make status bar black
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            Window window = getWindow();
            window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
            window.setStatusBarColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        }

        if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
            // Change toolbar color to the user's chosen color
            getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#" + user.getColor())));

            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        }

        coordinatorLayout = (CoordinatorLayout) findViewById(R.id.coordinatorLayout);

        swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipeRefreshLayout);
        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);

        username = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.username);
        userNumPosts = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.userNumPosts);

        userBackground = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.userBackground);
        userColor = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.userColor);
        userIcon = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.userIcon);

        username.setText(user.getUsername());
        userNumPosts.setText(user.getNumPosts());

        userColor.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#" + user.getColor()));

        // Add the user icon
        Glide.with(this)
                .load(user.getIcon())
                .into(userIcon);

        // Add the user background
        Glide.with(this)
                .load(user.getBackgroundImage())
                .into(userBackground);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);

        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

        userAdapter = new UserAdapter(this, data);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(userAdapter);

        userAdapter.setUserAdapterListener(new UserAdapter.UserAdapterListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRequestRefresh() {
                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
                getUserData(1);
            }
        });

        scrollListener = new EndlessRecyclerViewScrollListener(layoutManager) {
            @Override
            public void onLoadMore(int page, int totalItemsCount, RecyclerView view) {
                getUserData(page);
            }
        };

        recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(scrollListener);

        getUserData(1);
    }

    public void getUserData(final int page) {
        ApiInterface apiService = ApiClient.createService(ApiInterface.class, userAuthToken);

        Call<BasicResponse> call = apiService.getUserData(userId, page);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<BasicResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<BasicResponse> call, Response<BasicResponse> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    // Show the data

                    List<Message> messageData = response.body().getData();

                    data.addAll(messageData);

                    userAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }

                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<BasicResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                // 
            }
        });
    }
}
```

What could be causing my activity to lag when it's being loaded? Should I be putting all of my main code in `onCreate()`?

Comment: I would sprinkle some log statements through there and then look at the timestamps.  You should see a delay between two of them, and that will tell you where the problem is.  My guess is the database stuff, though maybe Glide, I'm not familiar with that.

Comment: Glide is supposed to be asynchronous.
@user198122 The layout seems to be massively complex, maybe this is the issue. Can you post it?

Comment: Just add some logs and then check in logcat your timing[.](https://android-app-promotion.com/)

Answer (score 2):

You have too much process in `onCreate()`. try to move some method to `onResume()`. In other words, you are blocking your UI with your data processing. Then, in layout, please minimized the use of nested layout. If the layout have to many children, the app will render it slower. Also consider designing/loading your UI before the data. This would allow your user to see something, even if its not complete.

P/s : Consider moving your Data/Process to an `AsyncTask`. or `Thread`

Answer (score 0):

I have look for solution too, this is worked for me

```
overridePendingTransition(0,0);
```

before starting the lagging activity.